# what happens when multiple instances of a single trigger is initiated?

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, after-trigger

Lets say in this instance, you have 50 users that are on salesforce. There's a after insert trigger created on the Account object.

What happens when all 50 of those users insert a new Account record? Does the trigger just run one by one until all 50 are completed? If this is the case, what are best practices to mitigate downsides when dealing with triggers that might take a long time to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user will receive their own transaction. They do not run "one at a time" but will run in parallel (concurrently) if possible. This depends on which rows are locked for editing at the time. For example, 50 users editing 50 accounts at once is fine, but 50 users editing 50 contacts on the same account is likely going to throw "unable to lock row" for some, perhaps even most, of the users.

If these transactions may potentially take more than 5 seconds, some transactions may be rejected. This is noted in the [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) documentation:

> Number of synchronous concurrent transactions for long-running transactions that last longer than 5 seconds for each org.<sup>2</sup> 10

With a footnote:

> If more transactions are started while the 10 long-running transactions are still running, they’re denied. HTTP callout processing time isn’t included when calculating this limit.

It's a best practice to try and optimize your code to try and fit within this five second limit to minimize the risk of errors for users. Use asynchronous code as much as possible and optimize your code. Also, make sure you perform explicit row locks (the SOQL "FOR UPDATE") keyword when you know you're going to update records, as this lock is much more forgiving than performing a DML, which throws an "unable to lock row" almost immediately.

Answer (score 2):

These will act as 50 different transactions as these are initiated by different users.